# PhantomJS выдаёт ошибку java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NEW_SESSION

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Всем привет!

Я написал код, запустил его. Сначала всё работает хорошо, но потом возникает ошибка.

Вывод ошибки в консоли:

```
ноя 24, 2016 1:01:26 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: executable: C:\Seo-Fast-Bot.beta\SFB.veta\phantomjs-2.1.1-  
windows\bin\phantomjs.exe
ноя 24, 2016 1:01:26 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: port: 39550
ноя 24, 2016 1:01:26 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: arguments: [--webdriver=39550, --webdriver-logfile=C:\Seo-Fast-Bot.beta\SFB.veta\phantomjsdriver.log]
ноя 24, 2016 1:01:26 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: environment: {}
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NEW_SESSION
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:82)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.<init>(DriverCommandExecutor.java:46)
at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.<init>(PhantomJSDriver.java:107)
at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.<init>(PhantomJSDriver.java:96)
at start.main(start.java:13)
```

Листинг кода:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;



public class start { 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, "C:\\Seo-Fast-Bot.beta\\SFB.veta\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe");
    WebDriver d = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
    d.get("http://ww.google.com");
}
}
```

Comment: похоже на проблему несовместимости библиотек, т.е. где-то слишком старая или слишком новая либа.

Comment: @Vartlok, Спасибо, за ваш ответ, сейчас попробую поменять библиотеки , затем вам напишу

Comment: @Vartlok, Спасибо!!!!!, всё работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

старая версия библиотеки selenium-remote-client